# Determining Correct Memory For ProLiant ML115

Tags: memory, hp

I'm upgrading the memory on a HP ProLiant ML115 server for a client so I went out onsite today to figure out what kind of memory he needed. I figured I would make note of the model number and look up the specs since I couldn't power down the machine to pop out the memory today.

Looking on the front of the case it had the standard ML115 stamp but on the side panel there were instructions for the G5 model.

I made note of the processor within Windows so I could go back into the specs later to see which model he actually had. It turns out he had the processor for the standard ML115 model not the G5. (AMD Opteron 1214)

According to [HP's Specs](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12704_div/12704_div.PDF), the AMD Opteron 1214 CPU supports PC2-5300 but according to [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_Opteron_microprocessors#Opteron_1200-series_.22Santa_Ana.22_.2890_nm.29), that processor only supports PC2-6400 memory (The same memory you see in the G5)

How do I determine the correct memory to buy based on the only solid piece of info that I have? (CPU)

Answer (score 1):

You always consult the vendor and stick to the supported product numbers. [In the ML 115 G5 QuickSpec document](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/V2/GetPDF.aspx/c01424137.pdf) it lists the RAM type as being PC2-6400 unbuffered DDR2 ECC 800MHz. Furthermore, the official product numbers for the HP RAM are listed as being:

```
HP 2GB (1x2GB) Dual Rank PC2-6400 (DDR2-800) Unbuffered Memory Kit 450260-B21
HP 1GB (1x1GB) Dual Rank PC2-6400 (DDR2-800) Unbuffered Memory Kit 450259-B21
```

You mention something that puzzles me, however:

> Looking on the front of the case it had the standard ML115 stamp but
>   on the side panel there were instructions for the G5 model.

Great! So that means you have the fifth generation of HP's servers, specifically the ML 115 model within that fifth generation.

> I made note of the processor within Windows so I could go back into
>   the specs later to see which model he actually had. It turns out he
>   had the processor for the standard ML115 model not the G5. (AMD
>   Opteron 1214)

The ML 115 G5 did have an Opteron 1214 option. There's no "standard model" for the ML 115. There's different build-outs within each generation, so... I'm in a bit of a quandary as to what you mean.

Nevertheless, snag the RAM you see in the QuickSpec guid and you'll be good to go.

Comment: The G5 model supports the Opteron CPU but not the 1200 series, only the 1300. If you look at the quick specs for the standard ML115 you'll see that the 1200 series is supported, the exact cpu that is in the server I'm referring to. The puzzling thing is that the front of the case simply says "ML115" while the inner part of the side panel has instructions for the G5. Wouldn't G5 be listed on the front if it was a true G5? You can see why this is confusing.

Comment: @user970638 No, the ML 115 G5 did not show "G5" on the faceplate. I just checked the last ML 115 I have still in use and it merely says "HP ProLiant ML 115" on the front, down at the bottom of the case. Grainy shot of my server on deployment day many moons ago: http://i.imgur.com/kIYiqhz.png As for the 1200 series, I don't know what to tell you, man. HP partners were selling supported Opteron 1214s by the truckload back in the day.

Answer (score 0):

I would call HP and give them the serial number, they can tell you what shipped with it, it's really your best bet next to cracking open the case.

Comment: *Dell* does that. HP doesn't have that insight into the original order.